# Angular2 Filter Data using input box of another component using pipe

Tags: angular

I have an angular2 app where I have structure like this

> body component
>
> -- body top component
>
> -- body bottom component

I have an input box "**Filter Data**" in top component, and a **data table** in body bottom component and a pipe "**filterData**"

body top component ::

```
<input [(ngModel)]="searchInputBox" type="text" name="searchInputBox" >
```

body bottom component ::

```
<tr *ngFor="let d of data | filterData:searchInputBox"><td>{{d.name}}</td></tr>
```

The problem is that it is not filtering data if I put input box and data table in two different components but it works fine if I put in one component.

How to pass input value from one component to another component to use in pipe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the most common approaches to solving the problem of shared state between components is the use of a `Service` which holds the data and can be injected into your various components.

[The Angular cookbook provides an example of this approach](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html). Just scroll down to the section titled `Parent and children communicate via a service`

Answer (score 2):

Components, in Angular 2, much like controllers in AngularJS, define their own "scope" in which they do their work. While in AngularJS, there were some tricks to access data from parent's scope, this is not the case anymore with Angular 2.

As @mohammad-shahid mentioned, you could use a Service to keep your data there, since that is a singleton object, and will be the same in your application, but, in my opinion, this is a little too much for what you need.

Instead, you should use a more Angular 2-like approach and make use of Observables, using the [rxjs](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS) library and a global state.

Then, you would have this structure:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';

@Injectable()
export class GlobalState {

    private _data = new Subject<Object>();
    private _dataStream$ = this._data.asObservable();

    private _subscriptions: Map<string, Array<Function>> = new Map<string, Array<Function>>();

    constructor() {
        this._dataStream$.subscribe((data) => this._onEvent(data));
    }

    notifyDataChanged(event, value) {

        let current = this._data[event];
        if (current !== value) {
            this._data[event] = value;

            this._data.next({
                event: event,
                data: this._data[event]
            });
        }
    }

    subscribe(event: string, callback: Function) {
        let subscribers = this._subscriptions.get(event) || [];
        subscribers.push(callback);

        this._subscriptions.set(event, subscribers);
    }

    _onEvent(data: any) {
        let subscribers = this._subscriptions.get(data['event']) || [];

        subscribers.forEach((callback) => {
            callback.call(null, data['data']);
        });
    }
}
```

Provide the GlobalState in the root component so you can access it anywhere.

And then you have the TopComponent

```
@Component(...)
TopComponent implements NgOninit {

    constructor (private _state: GlobalState) { }

    ngOnInit () {
        this._state.notifyDataChanged('myEvent', this.searchArg);
    }
}
```

And in the BottomComponent

```
@Component(...)
TopComponent implements NgOninit {

    constructor (private _state: GlobalState) { }

    ngOnInit () {
        this._state.subscribe('myEvent', (searchArg) => { // use it })
    }
}
```

Now, when the TopComponent will push data on the global state, the BottomComponent will react accordingly.

Comment: It looks good but I am only confused about this "Provide the GlobalState in the root component so you can access it anywhere". I am including and initializing GlobalState in both components if I don't do so it gives error.

Comment: On keyup of input box it is not passing/changing data to another component.

Comment: @MohammadShahid The GlobalState has to be imported everywhere it is used, yes, but since it's a service, you also need to include it in the `providers` array of some component, say RootComponent. You should check if the function is called with the correct search input on key press. Also note that the current form of the GlobalState class I've written doesn not push a value on the stream if it's equal to the last one pushed (`if (current) !== value)`)